# Amazon Marketplace feed - Issue in calculating MD5 hash

Tags: php, xml, curl, hash, amazon-mws

I know that the question related to this topic has been asked many times and i have read all but still not able to solve my problem. Here is my code...

```
<?php
define('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID','xxxxx');
define('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY','xxxxx');
define('MERCHANT_ID','xxxxx');
define('MARKETPLACE_ID','xxxxxx');

$file = 'test.xml';

$feed = '
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
          <Header>
               <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
               <MerchantIdentifier>Mystore</MerchantIdentifier>
          </Header>
          <MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
          <Message>
               <MessageID>123456</MessageID>
               <OrderFulfillment>
                     <AmazonOrderID>123-1234567-1234567</AmazonOrderID>
                     <MerchantFulfillmentID>1474290171</MerchantFulfillmentID>
                     <FulfillmentDate>2016-09-19T12:23:41+00:00</FulfillmentDate>
                     <FulfillmentData>
                            <CarrierCode>FedEx</CarrierCode>
                            <ShippingMethod>FedEx</ShippingMethod>
                            <ShipperTrackingNumber>1111111</ShipperTrackingNumber>
                     </FulfillmentData>

               </OrderFulfillment>
          </Message>
      </AmazonEnvelope>
   ';

$feedHandle = @fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($feedHandle, trim($feed));
rewind($feedHandle);

$params = array(
    'AWSAccessKeyId' => AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    'Action' => "SubmitFeed",
    'Merchant' => MERCHANT_ID,
    'SignatureVersion' => "2",
    'Timestamp'=> gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time()),
    'Version'=> "2009-01-01",
    'SignatureMethod' => "HmacSHA256",
    'FeedType' => '_POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_',
    'MarketplaceIdList.Id.1' => MARKETPLACE_ID,
    'PurgeAndReplace' => 'false',
);

$url_parts = array();
foreach(array_keys($params) as $key)
    $url_parts[] = $key . "=" . str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($params[$key]));

sort($url_parts);

$url_string = implode("&", $url_parts);
$string_to_sign = "POST\nmws.amazonservices.com\n/Feeds/2009-01-01\n" . $url_string;

// Sign the request
$signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $string_to_sign, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, TRUE);

$signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));

$url = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Feeds/2009-01-01" . '?' . $url_string . "&Signature=" . $signature;

$md5 = base64_encode(md5(trim($feed), true));

$httpHeader=array();
$httpHeader[]='Transfer-Encoding: chunked';
$httpHeader[]='Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8';
$httpHeader[]='Content-MD5: ' . $md5;
$httpHeader[]='Expect:';
$httpHeader[]='Accept:';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, '<MWS_SubmitFeed>/<1.02> (Language=PHP/' . phpversion() . ')');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $feedHandle);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpHeader);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
?>
```

When I submit the request I am getting the following error:

> SenderContentMD5DoesNotMatchthe Content-MD5 HTTP header you passed for your feed did not match the Content-MD5 we calculated for your feed4f0c5178-8971-4322-ba85-aed0bfe81bd0

Actually i am updating the order status on MWS.

Would be appreciated if anyone sort out the problem or point out that where i am going to wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a trim on the xml and then calculating the `md5`. Whereas the amazon is not doing any trim on the xml that you send. Hence the mismatch. Remove that `trim()` from there.

Comment: No luck, after removing trim(), still getting the same error and when echo the md5, it prints like that: GFhBmvap+b32ZJS7MLvRzQ==

Comment: Ok, i got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got the Solution.
Remove the trim() from these lines suggested by Sabuj Hassan and modify the hash generating code:

```
fwrite($feedHandle, trim($feed));
```

to

```
fwrite($feedHandle, $feed);
```

and

```
$md5 = base64_encode(md5(trim($feed), true));
```

to

```
$md5 = base64_encode(md5(stream_get_contents($feedHandle), true));
```

Replace trim($feed) to stream_get_contents($feedHandle), it will generate the correct hash for content-md5.

> **Note:** **stream_get_contents($feedHandle)** is mentioned in amazon's php library.